# Why does the string have plus signs in it?

Tags: javascript, stream

I create a string by reading from a stream:

```
converterProcess.stdout.on("data", async (data) => {
  buffer += data;
  console.log("on data", { buffer });
});
```

When I print the string:

```
  console.log({ buffer });
```

It has a lot of plus signs in it, as if the the concatenation logic hasn't been applied yet. This is different from what I would have expect.

```
 '\r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 10% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 10% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 20% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 20% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 30% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 30% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 40% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 50% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 60% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 70% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 80% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 90% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Progress <|> 100% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> animate <|> Result <|> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n' +
    '<?tgml 2.0?>\r\r\n' +
    '<!--[DocumentInformation]\r\n' +
    'Created: 2020-07-07 08:17\r\n' +
    'Modified: 2020-07-07 08:17\r\n' +
    '-->\r\r\n' +
    '<Tgml Height="10" Stretch="Uniform" Width="10">\r\r\n' +
    '  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="animate">\r\r\n' +
    '    <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10">\r\r\n' +
    '      <Animate Attribute="Fill" CalcMode="Linear" Duration="2" From="#0000FF" To="#FF0000"/>\r\r\n' +
    '    </Rectangle>\r\r\n' +
    '  </Layer>\r\r\n' +
    '</Tgml>\r\r\n' +
    ' <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 40% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 50% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 60% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 70% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 80% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 90% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Progress <|> 100% complete <|> 10 <| \r\n' +
    ' |> basic-shapes <|> Result <|> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n' +
    '<?tgml 2.0?>\r\r\n' +
    '<!--[DocumentInformation]\r\n' +
    'Created: 2020-07-07 08:17\r\n' +
    'Modified: 2020-07-07 08:17\r\n' +
    '-->\r\r\n' +
    '<Tgml Height="400" Stretch="Uniform" Width="600">\r\r\n' +
    '  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="basic-shapes">\r\r\n' +
    '    <Group Id="prefix__main">\r\r\n' +
    '      <Line Stroke="#0000CC" StrokeWidth="5" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="200"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Polyline Fill="None" Points="580,10 560,390 540,200 520,390 400,390" Stroke="#CC0000" StrokeWidth="5"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Polygon Fill="#FFFFCC" Points="350,75 379,161 469,161 397,215 423,301 350,250 277,301 303,215 231,161 321,161" Stroke="#FFFF00" StrokeWidth="10"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Rectangle Fill="#00FF00" Height="100" Left="100" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="20" Stroke="#006600" StrokeWidth="8" Top="10" Width="150"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Ellipse Fill="#FF66FF" Height="160" Left="20" Stroke="#990099" StrokeWidth="10" Top="220" Width="160"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Ellipse Fill="#00FFFF" Height="60" Left="370" Stroke="#00CCCC" StrokeWidth="10" Top="20" Width="160"/>\r\r\n' +
    '      <Text Fill="None" FontFamily="sans-serif" FontSize="50" Left="240" Stroke="#0000FF" Top="351.219"><![CDATA[SVG]]></Text>\r\r\n' +
    '    </Group>\r\r\n' +
    '  </Layer>\r\r\n' +
    '</Tgml>\r\r\n' +
    ' <| \r\n'
```

Questions:

- Why has the concatenation logic not been applied? (sorry if I am using incorrect terminology, feel very free to educate me)
- How can I apply the concatenation logic before printing to console?

Comment: can you put the output of what you are getting from console.log ?

Comment: @A.RAZIK: I get as output what is in the last code section of the question, except that I have stripped the "object wrapper" { buffer: ... } from the output.